# Como Capturar Imagem da Câmera do Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou com problemas para abrir a câmera, que irá fazer a captura de imagens para tirar fotos e salvá-las, no Android Studio utilizando emuladores. Segue o código abaixo:

CameraActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAPTURAR_IMAGEM = 1;
    private Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURAR_IMAGEM) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mostrarMensagem("Imagem capturada!");
            adicionarNaGaleria();
        } else {
            mostrarMensagem("Imagem não capturada!");
        }
    }
}

private void mostrarMensagem(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(this, msg,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

private void adicionarNaGaleria() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(uri);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public void capturarImagem(View v){
    boolean temCamera = getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    if(temCamera) {
        File diretorio = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String nomeImagem = diretorio.getPath() + "/" +
                System.currentTimeMillis() +
                ".jpg";
        uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem));

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURAR_IMAGEM);
    }
}
public void visualizarImagem(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

activity_camera.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testarcamera.CameraActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCapturarImagem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/capturarImagem"
            android:onClick="capturarImagem"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnVisualizarImagem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/visualizarImagem"
            android:onClick="visualizarImagem"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="26"
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Pesquisei em vários lugares, seguindo passo a passo do que falaram, porém ainda não achei o erro. Está acontecendo tudo certo, porém quando clico no botão para abrir a câmera e tirar foto, ele diz que o app parou de funcionar e fecha ele. Coloquei as permissões que diziam para colocar no AndroidManifest.xml, mas mesmo assim não adiantou. Mudei as configurações dos emuladores que utilizo na parte da câmera para usar Webcam0 e não funcionou, então coloquei para usar Emulated e também não deu. Alguém pode me ajudar pra eu saber qual é o problema e o que fazer? Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca o erro exato que deu que facilita para entender o problema.

Comment: Em qual versão do Android você está testando? Da versão 6.0 (API 23) em diante, [o usuário tem que dar permissão pro app acessar a câmera e o armazenamento do dispositivo](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)